# Accessing the integers of an array in C language

Tags: arrays, c

I am sorry if this is an elementary question but when I tried to do some operations on an array such as [1,2,3,4,5], I get completely different integers like this ---> [268501009, 0, 1378144, 0, 0]

I could not figure out how can I solve this problem. Is there something wrong with the void function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxN 30
void rotate(int v[maxN], int n, int p, int dir);

int main() {
    int n, v[maxN], tmp;
    while (1){
        printf("(Number integers in the array) n = "); scanf("%d", &n);
        //condition of n
        if ((n<=0) || (n > maxN)){
            printf("\n*Error! : n should be in the range (0,30]\nPlease try again:\n");
        } else{
            //enter the elements of the array
            printf("\nPlease enter %d integers:\n", n);
            for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
                scanf("%d", &tmp);
                v[i] = tmp;
            }
            //print the original array
            printf("\nThe array is the following:\n");
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                if (j == 0){
                    printf("[%d, ", v[j]);
                } else if (j == (n-1)){
                    printf("%d]", v[j]);
                } else{
                    printf("%d, ", v[j]);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    // print the rotated array
    printf("\n\n");
    int flag=1;
    int dir, p;
    while (flag){
        printf("\nPlease enter the direction (dir)\n( -1' for Right / '1' for Left) : ");
        scanf("%d", &dir);
        printf("\nPlease enter the number of iterations 'p' (if [p <= 0] the program will be terminated) : ");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        if (((dir == -1) || (dir == 1)) && (p > 0)){
            rotate(&v[n], n, p, dir);
        }else if((dir != -1) && (dir != 1)){
            printf("\n*Error!* : dir must be -1 or 1 \nPlease try again:\n");
        }
        else if(p <= 0){
            flag = 0;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}


void rotate(int v[maxN], int n, int p, int dir){

    if (dir == -1){       //to the right
        int tmp, repeat=0;
        while (repeat < p){                           //iterate p times
            tmp = (int)v[n-1];
            for (int i=n-1; 0 <= i < n; i--){         //move to the right one time
                if ((i-1) < 0){
                    v[0] = tmp;
                }else{
                    v[i] = v[i-1];
                }
            }
            repeat++;
        }

    }
    else if (dir == 1){      //to the left
        int tmp, repeat=0;
        while (repeat < p){                           //iterate p times
            tmp = (int)v[0];
            for (int i=0; i < n; i++){         //move to the right one time
                if ((i+1) == n){
                    v[n-1] = tmp;
                }else{
                    v[i] = v[i+1];
                }
            }
            repeat++;
        }
    }
    //print the rotated array
    printf("\nThe array is the following:\n");
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        if (j == 0){
            printf("[%d, ", v[j]);
        } else if (j == (n-1)){
            printf("%d]", v[j]);
        } else{
            printf("%d, ", v[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: in the first part before the rotation , the array gets saved perfectly . are you talking that you get those random values after the rotaiton ?

Comment: Too much code, no one wants to read through all this to find where something could go wrong.
Try and post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: exactly! after applying the 'rotate' function, I got those values

Comment: Why are you passing `&v[n]` to `rotate`? Shouldn't `rotate` be given the starting-address of the array?

Comment: I got his error so I added  the & sign :"Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int *'; take the address with &"

Comment: But why do you have `[n]` there? You're taking the address of the n+1:th element.

Comment: `0 <= i < n` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Oh okay. Now i removed <n and it works perfectly. But can I ask you why it didn’t work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your issue here ,

```
            rotate(&v[n], n, p, dir);
```

maybe you're confused on how to send an array via a function .
if you have an array like this `int v[n]` and you want to send it via a function , you have to type it like this

```
rotate(v, n, p, dir);
```

then in the function

```
void rotate(int v[maxN], int n, int p, int dir){
```

that's the only bug i see in your function , unless you got again unexpected values ...  [read this more about arrays and functions](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays-functions)

Comment: no problem and don't hesitate to reask if you still have issues @Nautilus